# Decimal number in axis tick using: "x tick=data"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have found the following problem during the building of an histogram:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[title=Istogramma di distribuzione,
title style={xshift=30mm},
ylabel={Frequenza $[n]$}, ylabel style={font=\footnotesize},
xlabel={Misurazione $[mm]$}, xlabel style={font=\footnotesize},
width=12cm, height=8cm,
axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left,
ymajorgrids, ytick=data, ybar,
xtick=data, x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
ymin=0, ymax=10, xmin=11.4, xmax=12.9,]
\addplot [fill=white, very thick] coordinates {
(   11.5    ,   1   )
(   11.6    ,   1   )
(   11.7    ,   2   )
(   11.8    ,   2   )
(   11.9    ,   4   )
(   12.0    ,   5   )
(   12.1    ,   7   )
(   12.2    ,   9   )
(   12.3    ,   8   )
(   12.4    ,   4   )
(   12.5    ,   4   )
(   12.6    ,   1   )
(   12.7    ,   1   )
(   12.8    ,   1   )
(0,3) (0,6)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this way I see all my data with the decimal number except 12!
What can I do in order to show the numbers after the comma anyway?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).